# Database growth - How to handle with big tables

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql

My SQL Server database is getting bigger and bigger. Nowadays, with 2 GB, it's increasing a lot with many data. I have some table with a lot of data, like millions. These data are very important for SELECTS, like graphics and reports.

I expect that in one more year, I'll have about 5-6 million rows in one of the tables. I have indexes, the database is well organized... my unique worry is about the time that it will take to generate some reports and so on...

How to find data, SUM, COUNT, check 'n' variables based on columns, in so big tables?

What can you suggest? Is there a way to reorganize or split tables? I'm worried in the situation to use always the better manner and make everything look OK.

Comment: You should probably remove the postgresql tag. There are many solutions for performance improvements. For starters, read about indexes. 2Gb is not big. 2 million rows is not big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an ordinary transactional database, you can go for a data warehousing solution for your reporting purposes.

Data warehouses are usually more efficient in these type of situations.